# How do you cover a part of a div with another div, like a card?

Tags: html, css, layout

I want to create a layout, where there are 3 divs in the "background", and one div in front but it does not cover all the screen, it is just like a "pop-up" (but it is always there).
This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

The white div is the one that should be in front. The green div at the top will have buttons, so the background divs are not just pictures, and later I want my website to be responsive.

What is the idea behind making these kinds of layout? Can you suggest some techniques? How would you do it? (I would appriciate basic codes, but advice is always welcome.)

Comment: What have you tried yourself? I know how to fix this, but I think you wont learn too much by just copy pasting my solution.

Comment: this is the best I can come up with. https://jsfiddle.net/shanemendez/x24bj37m/13/, maybe `calc` can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something like this, hope it helps.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  background: white;
}

.DivRow {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 40%;
}

#row1 {
  background: #23B14D;
}

#row2 {
  background: #00A3E8;
}

#row3 {
  background: #B5E41A;
}

.DivColumn {
  margin: 20px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  width: 34%;
  height: 90%;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="DivRow">
    <div id="row1"></div>
    <div id="row2"></div>
    <div id="row3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="DivColumn"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. Use 4 `div` blocks and give them al a color. The last one is the white one and you give it an `absolute` position. Add `margin` and `height` to all the `div` and you create your image.

The example:

```css
.top,
.middle,
.bottom {
  height: calc(100vh / 3); /* Fill the viewport width 3 boxes */
}

.top {
  background: #008000; /* Green background color */
}

.middle {
  background: #0000FF; /* Blue background color */
}

.bottom {
  background: #00FF00; /* Lime background color */
}

.center {
  position: absolute; /* places this div on top */
  top: 0; /* Position the div on the top */
  right: 0; /* Position the div on the right */
  bottom: 0; /* Position the div on the bottom */
  left: 0; /* Position the div on the left */
  background: #FFF; /* White background color */
  margin: 80px; /* Makes sure you can see the other dives */
  height: calc(100vh - 160px); /* Add the viewport height minus the top and bottom marin */
}
```

```html
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="middle"></div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
<div class="center"></div>
```

Try adding `media queries` to the `margin` or `max-width` to make it responsive. If you want to put all the content in the whitebox and make it scroll, add `overflow-y: auto`.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to organize sections with responsiveness without the need to use media queries is using the CSS grid. It is an amazing tool and you use much less code to this. I recommend you to read this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ and get familiar with the CSS grid. it will solve more than your problems. You can see below how I solved your problem with much less code than usual. I hope this answers your question. don't forget to put a flag if you liked my solution! have a nice day of code :)

```css
.container{
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr  80% 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 4fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.div1{
    background-color:#27ae60;
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    grid-row:1 / 3;
}

.div2{
  background-color:#0c2461;
  grid-column:1 / -1;
  grid-row: 3 / 4;
}


.div3{
  background-color:#b8e994;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  grid-row: 4 / 6;
}

.div4{
  background-color:white;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 2 / 5;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2"></div>
  <div class="div3"></div>
  <div class="div4"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

After a little bit of effort I came up with [this](https://jsfiddle.net/shanemendez/x24bj37m/26/)

### Lets dig into it a little bit

The html is pretty simple

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="row" id="item1"></div>
    <div class="row" id="item2"></div>
    <div class="row" id="item3"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="top"></div>
</div>
```

we've got an upper level container `#app`, a container for our layers `div.flex`
and `div.top`, the element we'll be positioning atop.

The css starts off with some boilerplate, just to get things started

```
html,body{
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.flex{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#item1{
  background: teal;
}
#item2{
  background: pink;
}
#item3{
  background:orange;
}
```

the `html, body` bit is just to make the demo look good in jsfiddle. Otherwise it would be offset. Gross.

We then define `.flex` so that each of it's elements fill the container i.e. flexes  across all `columns` left to right

finally we give each element `.row` a color

With this we end up with 3 band of color of equal size all evenly spaced within the div

### The interesting part

```
#app{
  position: relative;
}
#top{  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
  margin: 20px;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
}
```

Now here I have to admit that my understanding is a bit shaky, if I'm wrong please correct me.

What we want now is for `#top` to break the normal flow of the layout. We don't want it to simply be placed below the previous div. To do that we can say `position: absolute`, however that on it's own is not enough.

`position: absolute` looks for the nearest ancestor with `position: relative` and aligns itself with that ancestor. So if we want to position `#top` relative to its container `#app`

```
#app{
  position: relative;
}
#top{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

`top:0` aligns `#top` to the top of `#app`. Play around with it in the fiddle to get a solid grasp.

### Finally

```
#top{  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

we want a small margin around the edge of `#top` so we can see the colors behind, and we've got that covered with `margin: 20px`. Now we need to subtract `2 * margin` from the `width` and `height` to line everything up correctly

```
#top{  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
  margin: 20px;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
}
```

Hope this helps!

## Fin

P.S. Play with the numbers in the fiddle. That should help a lot

```css
html,body{
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
div{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.flex{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#item1{
  background: teal;
}
#item2{
  background: pink;
}
#item3{
  background:orange;
}

#app{
  position: relative;
}
#top{  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
  margin: 20px;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="row" id="item1"></div>
    <div class="row" id="item2"></div>
    <div class="row" id="item3"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="top"></div>
</div>
```